# Revenue Date Tracking and Field Updating Based on Business Days

Tags: workflow

We currently have a field on our Project Revenue Object called "Submitted Date/Revenue Date" and a field called "Revenue Status". We would like to update the "Revenue Status" field from "CC Submitted" to "CC Completed" after 10 business days. But if at anytime the Revenue Status gets moved out of CC Submitted to one of the prior values or is moved to a blank status we would like the 10 business day count to stop. Is this possible. I have the formula for the 10 business day count as:

```
CASE(
    MOD( CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c - DATE( 1900, 1, 7), 7),
    5, CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c + 17,
    6, CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c + 16,
        CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c + 15
)
```

Where I am stuck is how to get this into a workflow rule where I can do a field update because it seems that I would also have to have something that determines if the date field is blank. For example, `NOT(ISBLANK(CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c))` which would determine if the 10 business days gets counted.

Can this be done in one workflow rule?

Comment: You should be able to do this in a workflow rule. You are able to set the criteria for the rule using a formula, and if you set the options for the rule correctly, you can ensure that any edits that make the formula turn to false will also ensure that the record is not updated. I would advise taking a closer look at the options for workflow rules, and returning here with a more specific question.

Comment: I tried writing the formula for the workflow rule based on the fact that there has to be a submitted date and using the case statement to count. I was trying to use an IF statement. IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c)),
CASE(
    MOD( CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c - DATE( 1900, 1, 7), 7),
    5, CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c + 17,
    6, CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c + 16,
        CC_Submitted_Date/Revenue_Date__c + 15
),

FALSE)
I am getting errors when trying to save.

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to save the formula? Not much anyone can do without that.

Comment: The error I am getting is : Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Date, received Boolean

Comment: For just the workflow criteria, try something like:

Comment: AND( NOT(ISBLANK(CC_Submitted_Date)), NOT(ISBLANK(Revenue_Date__c)))

Comment: Hello There, we do not have a seprate revenue date field. The name of the field is called "Submitted Date/Revenue Date". It is one field. What I am trying to accomplish for the workflow rule is that once a date is placed in that field to begin counting 10 business days from that date (which is the CASE statement above) and on the 10th business day update the "Revenue Status" Field from "Submitted" to "Completed"